# 4 Wheel Differential Drive Robot with different speeds

Tags: wheeled-robot, differential-drive, wheel

Differential drive robot with 4 wheels, 
If for example the back wheels were using different motors than the front ones ( ie : running at a faster/slower speed )
in general, would that generate more moving ( tourqe/force ) than having free ruining wheels instead ?
or using free running wheels would be a better option because of the slip related to the slower wheels ?

Note : its a sumo bot

Comment: are you asking if 4 motors are better than 2 motors?

Comment: @jsotola
essentially yes, but with keeping in mind that two of them are running at different speeds than the other two, which is pretty much causing slip, since slip in a way is having your wheels running at different speed than the robot.
so do i still get some extra push power or that just makes the whole thing worse ?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic friction is always lower than static friction. If you are purposefully putting your wheels into a slip mode, then you are putting the wheels into a condition where they have **less** traction.

For maximum pushing/stopping power, you would want your wheels torqued to the point just *before* they begin to slip. This is what anti-lock brakes do; an ABS system *reduces* braking pressure to prevent the wheels from locking up, which maximizes braking power.